# Displaying JPanels plus its components in a tab within a JFrame using each tab as a seperate class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtabbedpane

Please I need some help. I am trying to create a `JFrame` to contain Tabs, and each tab will show one panel. Each panel contains buttons and `Textfields`. The panels are should show a separate class on each tab but the panels show without the buttons and the `Textfields`. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CELTool extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

   JTabbedPane tab;

   public CELTool() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("CELTool");
      tab = new JTabbedPane();
      frame.add(tab, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      Illustration etool = new Illustration();
      tab.add("Illustration", etool);

      Encrypt crypt = new Encrypt();
      tab.add("Crypt", crypt);

      Decrypt decrypt = new Decrypt();

      tab.add("Decrypt", decrypt);

      frame.setSize(500, 750);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      CELTool clt = new CELTool();//        
      clt.setSize(400,500);     
      clt.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class Illustration extends JPanel {

   static String[] strPlaintext = {"Original Input", "InitialPermutation", "First RIound ", "Second Round",
                                   "Third Round", "Fourth Round", "Fifth Round", "Sixth Round", "Seventh Round",
                                   "Eight Round", "Ninth Round", "Tenth Round", "Eleventh Round", "Twelveth Round",
                                   "Thirteenth Round", "Fourtheenth Round", "Fithteenth Round", "Sixtheenth Round",
                                   "Final Round", "Ciphertext"};
   static String[] str2 = {"Key", "Round Sixteen", "Round Fithteen", "Round Fourteen", "Round Thirteen", "Round Twelve",
                           "Round Eleven", "Round Ten",};
   int leading, ascent, height, width;
   int leading2, ascent2, height2, width2;
   int xcoord = 40, ycoord = 100, xcoord2 = 600, ycoord2 = 60;
   static final int BORDER = 5;

   public void paint(Graphics gr) {
      super.paint(gr);
      int i = 0, xcoord = 40, ycoord = 100, xcoord2 = 600, ycoord2 = 60;


      leading = gr.getFontMetrics().getLeading();
      ascent = gr.getFontMetrics().getAscent();
      height = gr.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
      width = gr.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(strPlaintext[i]);

      for (i = 0; i < strPlaintext.length; i++) {
         gr.drawString(strPlaintext[i], xcoord, ycoord);
         leading = gr.getFontMetrics().getLeading();
         ascent = gr.getFontMetrics().getAscent();
         height = gr.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
         width = gr.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(strPlaintext[i]);
         gr.drawRect(xcoord - BORDER, ycoord - (ascent + leading + BORDER), width + 2 * BORDER, height + 2 * BORDER);
         ycoord += 40;

      }

   }
}

class Encrypt extends JPanel {

   public Encrypt() {
      JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();
      panel5.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());    //panel5.setLayout((LayoutManager) new GridBagConstraints());

      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      panel5.add(new JLabel("Input plaintext text"), gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 1;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      panel5.add(new JTextField("0123456789ABCDEF", 20), gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 2;
      panel5.add(new JLabel("Input text in Hex"), gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 1;
      gbc.gridy = 2;
      panel5.add(new JTextField("0123456789ABCDEF", 20), gbc);

      panel5.setSize(200, 300);
      panel5.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class Decrypt extends JPanel {

   JPanel decPanel;
   JTextField dectxt;

   public Decrypt() {
      decPanel = new JPanel();
      decPanel.add(new JLabel("Cipher"));
      decPanel.add(new JTextField());
      decPanel.add(new JLabel("key"));
      decPanel.add(new JTextField());
      decPanel.add(new JLabel("Plaintext"));
      decPanel.add(new JTextField());
      decPanel.add(new JButton("Decrypt"));
      decPanel.add(new JButton("Reset"));
      decPanel.validate();

   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two `JFrames`? You're already extending it.

Comment: Few things: 1) Almost always override `paintComponent` using Swing, not `paint`. 2) You're reassigning constant values in your loop (for the leading, ascent, and height of the text). 3) You are extending components, but instead of using `this`, you're creating new components and setting them to visible instead of adding them. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete fix at all, but at least something to get you going in the right direction. Compare it carefully with your code to see the differences. Hope this helps.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CELTool extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

   JTabbedPane tab;
   Illustration etool;
   Encrypt encrypt;
   Decrypt decrypt;

   private CELTool() {
      super("CELTool");

      tab = new JTabbedPane();
      etool = new Illustration();
      encrypt = new Encrypt();
      decrypt = new Decrypt();

      tab.add("Illustration", etool);
      tab.add("Crypt", encrypt);
      tab.add("Decrypt", decrypt);
      this.add(tab, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setSize(500, 750);
      this.pack();
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      this.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      // why blank?
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new CELTool();      
   }


private class Illustration extends JPanel {

   public Illustration(){

   }

   private final String[] strPlaintext = {"Original Input", "InitialPermutation", "First RIound ", "Second Round",
                                   "Third Round", "Fourth Round", "Fifth Round", "Sixth Round", "Seventh Round",
                                   "Eight Round", "Ninth Round", "Tenth Round", "Eleventh Round", "Twelveth Round",
                                   "Thirteenth Round", "Fourtheenth Round", "Fithteenth Round", "Sixtheenth Round",
                                   "Final Round", "Ciphertext"};
   private final String[] str2 = {"Key", "Round Sixteen", "Round Fithteen", "Round Fourteen", "Round Thirteen", "Round Twelve",
                           "Round Eleven", "Round Ten",};
   int leading, ascent, height, width;
   int xcoord = 40, ycoord = 100, xcoord2 = 600, ycoord2 = 60;
   private final int BORDER = 5;

   public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
      super.paintComponent(gr);
      int i = 0, xcoord = 40, ycoord = 100, xcoord2 = 600, ycoord2 = 60;

      leading = gr.getFontMetrics().getLeading();
      ascent = gr.getFontMetrics().getAscent();
      height = gr.getFontMetrics().getHeight();

      for (i = 0; i < strPlaintext.length; i++) {
         gr.drawString(strPlaintext[i], xcoord, ycoord);
         width = gr.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(strPlaintext[i]);
         gr.drawRect(xcoord - BORDER, ycoord - (ascent + leading + BORDER), width + 2 * BORDER, height + 2 * BORDER);
         ycoord += 40;
      }
   }
}

private class Encrypt extends JPanel {

   public Encrypt() {
      this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      this.add(new JLabel("Input plaintext text"), gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 1;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      this.add(new JTextField("0123456789ABCDEF", 20), gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 2;
      this.add(new JLabel("Input text in Hex"), gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 1;
      gbc.gridy = 2;
      this.add(new JTextField("0123456789ABCDEF", 20), gbc);

      this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
   }
}

private class Decrypt extends JPanel {

   public Decrypt() {
      this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
      this.add(new JLabel("Cipher"));
      this.add(new JTextField());
      this.add(new JLabel("key"));
      this.add(new JTextField());
      this.add(new JLabel("Plaintext"));
      this.add(new JTextField());
      this.add(new JButton("Decrypt"));
      this.add(new JButton("Reset"));
      this.validate();
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks paranoid-android it works.Thank you. i am new to java that is why i was not sure if i could use the instance of the class i create and extended from the JFrame. i will try to remove that JFrame and see how i can manage it without redefining JFrame. in most of the java example codes i have read there is always java.awt and javax.swing so i am not sure why although i have read that they are different.does it make any difference if i use paintComponent or just paint?

Comment: 1) If you're extending `JFrame` for example, then that class is a `JFrame`, so you can treat it as you would any `new JFrame()`. AWT and Swing are very different, and it may take some time to learn the differences and when not to mix them together. 2) I think reading the tutorial would give you a much better understanding. Java Tutorial: http://goo.gl/1zkR9